# TinyMCE - style single element of: insert date time plugin - font: bold, colour

Tags: css, tinymce, styling

I'm looking for help with how to style just one part of the TinyMCE insertdatetime_formats.

As an example:

I currently have this:
insertdatetime_formats: [ '✏️ (%d-%m-%Y)' ]

Result:
✏️ (29-5-23)

and I'd like to produce e.g. actual date in red/bold with bracket formatting unaltered:

[image: screen-grab of the text formatting I'd like to achieve. Date in Red Bold.]